# Getting a warning when trying to install composer on mac

Tags: macos, composer-php

I tried today to install the composer on my mac from terminal. I used this command to download and install the composer inside my users folder

> curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

but when I press the enter I've got the following warning.

> All settings correct for using Composer PHP Warning: 
>   file_put_contents(/Users/test/.composer/keys.dev.pub): failed to open
>   stream: Permission denied in - on line 468
>
> Warning: file_put_contents(/Users/test/.composer/keys.dev.pub): failed
>   to open stream: Permission denied in - on line 468 PHP Warning: 
>   file_put_contents(/Users/test/.composer/keys.tags.pub): failed to open
>   stream: Permission denied in - on line 485
>
> Warning: file_put_contents(/Users/test/.composer/keys.tags.pub): failed
>   to open stream: Permission denied in - on line 485 Downloading
>   1.2.0...
>
> Composer successfully installed to: /Users/test/composer.phar Use it:
>   php composer.phar

Because the warning has to do with permissions I deleted the composer.phar that has been created and I executed again the same command using composer, but still getting the same warning. How I can fix this warning?

UPDATE
I did

> curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php

and it worked, but I want to know why. Thanks

Comment: `ls -al /Users/test` – what's the permission of that directory and/or the `.composer` directory...? Are you user `test`?

Comment: it's not test user, I just renamed it on my post for not putting my actual user. here is the composer


drwxr-xr-x   32 test   staff    1088 Jul 21 22:19 .composer